# Getting count of distinct values across multiple tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, union

I have a DB that looks basically like this:

```
Table `person_dir`:
int person_ID
varchar firstname
varchar lastname
enum division

Table `prod_staff`:
int prod_ID
int staff_ID
int role_ID

Table `prod_cast`:
int prod_ID
int cast_ID
varchar role_name
```

What I'm trying to do is get the top 10 people in a given division, based on number of productions they've been involved in, either as a staff member or a cast member. It is possible for a person to act as both staff and cast in a given production, so just getting two COUNTs won't give an accurate number.

The query I have looks like this:

```
SELECT pers_ID, firstname, lastname,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prod_ID) FROM (
            (SELECT prod_ID 
             FROM prod_staff 
             WHERE staff_ID = person_dir.person_ID)
            UNION
            (SELECT prod_ID
             FROM prod_cast 
             WHERE cast_ID = person_dir.person_ID)
        ) AS maxnum
    FROM person_dir
    WHERE division = 'north'
    ORDER BY maxnum DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

When I try to run it, I get an error saying there is a syntax error on the line with "FROM person_dir". Running the COUNT in a query by itself works, so I must be embedding it wrong. Any help in spotting the error would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try storing the UNION calculation in a #temp table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery needs to have a `SELECT` statement and be wrapped in parentheses. But you can't nest correlation 2 levels deep, so what you're writing won't work.

You can instead join with a subquery that gets the counts for every ID.

```
SELECT person_ID, firstname, lastname, maxnum
FROM person_dir
JOIN (
    SELECT person_ID, COUNT(*) AS maxnum FROM (
        SELECT staff_ID AS person_ID, prod_ID 
        FROM prod_staff 
        UNION
        SELECT cast_ID AS person_ID, prod_ID
        FROM prod_cast 
    ) AS x
    GROUP BY person_ID
) AS prodcount ON prodcount.person_ID = person_dir.person_ID
WHERE division = 'north'
ORDER BY maxnum DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You don't need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` because `UNION` removes duplicates by default.

Comment: This worked, with one modification. It needed a GROUP BY on the subquery. Thank you!

    SELECT person_ID, firstname, lastname, maxnum
FROM person_dir
JOIN (
    SELECT person_ID, COUNT(*) AS maxnum FROM (
        SELECT staff_ID AS person_ID, prod_ID 
        FROM prod_staff 
        UNION
        SELECT cast_ID AS person_ID, prod_ID
        FROM prod_cast 
    ) AS x
   GROUP BY person_ID
) AS prodcount ON prodcount.person_ID = person_dir.person_ID
WHERE division = 'north'
ORDER BY maxnum DESC
LIMIT 10